# Python 2.7.5 is not showing any traceback for sys.exit() in IDLE

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, automation

I have `sys.exit(0)`  in my script. But its not showing any trace back when i run the script in IDLE. I changed it to `sys.exit(1)` , still no difference. The same code is giving proper trace back and exit code in Python 2.7.3. Am i missing something in 2.7.5 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you do `sys.exit()`

Comment: Why would you expect a traceback? It's `sys.exit`; it's not supposed to cause a stack trace. There may be a `SystemExit` exception under the covers, but when the exception finishes unwinding the stack, Python catches it and exits.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Even though IDLE is not giving any trace back, its exiting with the correct exit code. As no trace back is given, i was not able to identify the from the script was exiting. So raised my concern.

sys.exit()also not giving any trace back